# Debezium transaction metadata - no `END` event received with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, debezium

I'm trying to get the [transaction metadata](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-transaction-metadata) working with debezium 1.4.1.Final using a SQL Server database.

It seems to be working to some extent - the `dbservername.transaction` topic has been created, and when I run a stored proc which contains a transaction, then the `"status":"BEGIN"` event is received, along with the CDC packets on the table topic.

However, no `"status":"END"` event is received... until I run the stored proc again.

It may very well be that I'm not closing the transaction in the stored proc correctly (I'm not a MSSQL expert by any means)...

This is the structure I'm using:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.myproc
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ...
    COMMIT;
END
GO
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get the `END` event at the end of the proc?

Comment: It says "Only committed changes are visible" from the main page of debezium Github: https://github.com/debezium/debezium Can it be the reason?

Comment: I think that's simply referring to the fact that the only events that will be published to Kafka are changes that have been committed within the database. The transaction metadata is useful for grouping multiple committed changes into a logical set by the consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no reliable way to emit the END event before the connector has received another transaction BEGIN event. Hence END events are delayed in case you don't have a continuous transaction load on your database.

You may consider to run some dummy transactions in a loop for triggering this. We're planning to support this OOTB via Debezium's heartbeat feature (see [DBZ-3263](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-3263)); any help with that will surely be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar. For those landing here from Google, more discussion here: https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/F9juhi4uKbI

Comment: looking through the code made me wonder , when ingesting multiple databases with the same connector, can one DB Begin TX message be suddenly closed by another DB LSN coming in from a different database if using a single task to monitor all DBs?